# searching a map in dart and returning all values matching search

Tags: flutter, dart, graphql

I have a map, with multiple layers, some of the layers have an events field which may contain 0 or more event listings inside of it.
Some of events are nested deeper into the map, while others are closer to the top layer.

Here is what the `graphql` query result looks like:

```json
    {
      "data": {
        "users": [
          {
            "id": 16,
            "friends": [
              {
                "senderId": 16,
                "receiverId": 17,
                "userByReceiverid": {
                  "id": 17,
                  "events": [],
                  "friends": [
                    {
                      "receiverId": 14,
                      "userByReceiverid": {
                        "id": 14,
                        "events": [
                          {
                            "id": 3,
                            "photoUrl": "none",
                            "name": "hello",
                            "date": "1982-06-27",
                            "startTime": "01:00:00+00",
                            "endTime": "02:00:00+00",
                            "fee": "$2.00",
                            "maxNumber": 10,
                            "ageRestriction": "none",
                            "about": "amazing",
                            "allowShare": false,
                            "private": false,
                            "timestamp": "2021-06-26T17:57:13.224383+00:00",
                            "senderId": 14
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "receiverId": 20,
                      "userByReceiverid": {
                        "id": 20,
                        "events": []
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ],
            "friendsByReceiverid": [
              {
                "senderId": 20,
                "receiverId": 16,
                "user": {
                  "id": 20,
                  "events": [],
                  "friendsByReceiverid": [
                    {
                      "receiverId": 20,
                      "user": {
                        "id": 14,
                        "events": [
                          {
                            "id": 3,
                            "photoUrl": "none",
                            "name": "hello",
                            "date": "1982-06-27",
                            "startTime": "01:00:00+00",
                            "endTime": "02:00:00+00",
                            "fee": "$2.00",
                            "maxNumber": 10,
                            "ageRestriction": "none",
                            "about": "amazing",
                            "allowShare": false,
                            "private": false,
                            "timestamp": "2021-06-26T17:57:13.224383+00:00",
                            "senderId": 14
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "receiverId": 20,
                      "user": {
                        "id": 17,
                        "events": []
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

I want to search the `Map` and make a list that contains all the events that are unique, so no duplicates if possible.

How would I go about pulling out only the events field from a map at any given point?

Comment: Please format your data. No one wants to read a dense paragraph of data text.

Comment: that's the way it came up when converted from a hashmap from a graphql query, i'll post the graphql reply under it from the client which is a lot nicer looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially what you need is a function (`visitObject`) that goes through each key of the a `Map` and recursively calls itself till all properties have been checked.

The function should also check for the possible types it can operate on and handle the data so you can call the `visitObject` function with the right arguments.

I believe the right data structure here would be a `Set`. In `dart` as `Set` is defined as *A collection of objects in which each object can occur only once.*
However `Set` a set falls back to the dart method of equality which is the `==` operator, so you would either need to use a calls for Events or use a package like `BuiltValue` which will generate the `==` operator for your value types.

Here is an example that can help you get started, I have left equality checking for you to determine what best and how you want to apply it.

```dart
final Set<Map<String, dynamic>> items = {};

void main() {
    visitObject(data);
}

void visitObject(object) {
  if (object is List) {
    for(dynamic item in object) {
      visitObject(item);
    }
  } else if (object is Map) {
    if (object.containsKey('events')) {
      var _events = object['events'];
      if (_events is List && _events.isNotEmpty) {
        _events.forEach((e) {
          if (!items.contains(e)) {
            items.add(e);
          }
        });
      }
    }
    for (dynamic item in object.values) {
      visitObject(item);
    }
  }
}
```

**Additional Reading for equality:**

- [==Operator](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html)
- [hashCode](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/Object/hashCode.html)
- [BuiltValue](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value)

Comment: Hey! Thank you, I think it works!! :) Where can go to learn how to do what you explained to me? What books/sites do you recommend? I want to get better with dart. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer with some resources for this question. The dart docs are a great place to start I'll post and update if i find any good resources about dart in general, there